# Number systems, squares and probability

Tags: trees, number-systems, sum-of-squares-method

first time posting. This has probably been found before, but I found it myself, exciting for me. Sorry if my math language is bad.
My question is about number systems with fractions/benath one.

I found that if you make a number tree, there's a pattern in amount of numbers. I mean a number tree like 00, 01, 10 and 11. This would be in the 2-digit system and you would have 2 "sets of branches". I found that the equation (x+highest digit in system)^branches would find the amount of zeros in one line (sub-branch). In a 2-digit system with 2 branches, as listed above would be 00, 01, 10 and 11, or $(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1$. The one with a square would be amount where there are no zeros, therefore one. The seconds part (2x) would tell us amount of subbranches with one zero, which is 2 (01, 10). I found this works for any number system. Are there anyone else that know where I can find more about this, and if it works with number systems below 1? Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: I don't totally follow, but if you were to write out all $n$-length bitstrings then exactly $\binom{n}{k}$ of them will contain exactly $k$ zeroes.  You can further recognize this as being the coefficients in the expansion of $(x+1)^n$.  The coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(x+1)^n$ will indeed be $\binom{n}{k}$, as per the binomial theorem.  This might be what you are getting at.

Comment: Now... the number of $n$-length strings over an $m$-character alphabet, the number of them with exactly $k$ zeroes will indeed be the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(x+m-1)^n$ which can be seen by binomial theorem to be $\binom{n}{k}(m-1)^{n-k}$ which can be explained combinatorially by first picking the positions where the zeroes go followed by picking what occupies each respective non-zero position.